# pull to refresh in scroll view android

Tags: android, android-layout

i am trying to show one gridview while selecting some photo from gallery and showing list with recyclerview in a fragment. my layout working well if i do not use swipe refresh layout. can you solve this why this layout not working while using swipe refreshlayout.

xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.systechdigital.webadeal.NewsfeedFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#969696"

    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#023956"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/globe"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/notificationButtonId"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            >

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Share you thoughts here..."
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_status_background"
                android:padding="20dp"
                android:elevation="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/editTextWritePostId"

                />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:background="#f9f9f9"
                >

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Post"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:background="#1470a6"
                    android:id="@+id/postButtonId"
                    />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/checkInButtonId"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/smileyButtonId"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_checkin"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/smiley"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageUploadButtonId"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/smileyButtonId"
                    />

                <ImageButton
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/camera"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/videoUploadButtonId"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imageUploadButtonId"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <GridView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/gridViewId"
                android:layout_below="@+id/postButtonId"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:columnWidth="100dp"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/underline"
                android:minHeight="0dp"
                />

            **<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayoutId"
                >**

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerviewId_newsFeed"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
                    />

            **</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>**

        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36337019/7134908), this will definitely help you.

Comment: not working.,,.,

Comment: Use NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView.

Comment: not working.,.,.

Answer (score 1):

**1.** Don't use `GridView`, `ListView` or `RecyclerView` inside `ScrollView`. Use `NestedScrollView` instead of your `ScrollView`.

> `NestedScrollView` is just like `ScrollView`, but it supports acting as
>   both a nested scrolling parent and child on both new and old versions
>   of Android.

**2.** Use `SwipeRefreshLayout` as parent of `NestedScrollView`.

**3.** Use attribute `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` to `LinearLayout` instead of `android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"`.

**4.** Use attribute `android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"` to `RecyclerView`.

**Update your layout as below:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#969696">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#023956">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_group"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/notificationButtonId"
            android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayoutId">

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Share you thoughts here..."
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:elevation="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/editTextWritePostId" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    android:background="#f9f9f9">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Post"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:background="#1470a6"
                        android:id="@+id/postButtonId" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/checkInButtonId"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/smileyButtonId"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_cart"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:layout_marginRight="3dp" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageUploadButtonId"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/smileyButtonId" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="@drawable/ic_camera"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imageUploadButtonId" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <GridView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/gridViewId"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/postButtonId"
                    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                    android:columnWidth="100dp"
                    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:minHeight="0dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerviewId_newsFeed"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: What is the current status after applying my changes?

Comment: same output as before.

Comment: can you solve me one more problem showing

"OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 20155404 byte allocation with 8428224 free bytes and 8MB until OOM"

Comment: Can you please try by replacing your `GridView` with `RecyclerView(with GridLayoutManager)`. Its suggested to use `RecyclerView` when using inside `NestedScrollView`

Comment: "OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 20155404 byte allocation with 8428224 free bytes and 8MB until OOM" >> Its happening due to your image grid. Use 3rd party library Glide or Picasso for loading image efficiently.

Comment: If you use `Glide` then method `.thumbnail(0.1f)` and if you use `Picasso` then `.resize(120,120)`. See details in `Glide` and `Picasso` documentation. If you don't want to use 3rd party lib, then make your own.

Comment: okay i used picasso and working fine.
 and i couldnt solve the problem the way you told but i did it by another layout.
but thank you so much for your cordial help

Comment: how about your new another layout?

Comment: working fine.actually i made separate layout and showed in alertdialog and working well. :)
and you are very good :)

Answer (score 0):

just replace your swipe view at top of your layout like this

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayoutId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#969696"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.systechdigital.webadeal.NewsfeedFragment"

        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#023956">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/notificationButtonId"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/globe" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editTextWritePostId"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittext_status_background"
                    android:elevation="5dp"
                    android:hint="Share you thoughts here..."
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"

                    />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="#f9f9f9"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/postButtonId"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#1470a6"
                        android:text="Post"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/checkInButtonId"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/smileyButtonId"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_checkin" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/smileyButtonId"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageUploadButtonId"
                        android:background="@drawable/smiley" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageUploadButtonId"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/videoUploadButtonId"
                        android:background="@drawable/camera" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/gridViewId"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/postButtonId"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:columnWidth="100dp"
                    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                    android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/underline"
                    android:minHeight="0dp" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerviewId_newsFeed"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true" />


            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: means it is not working., i want when i scroll everything will scroll up/down but not working